# bootstrap doen't work in angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I create add-to-cart app. I need each col in a row to display like it's mentioned `col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-6`. But it's displayed in a column (Maybe it doesn't work because I added `ng-repeat`? And this style is the same for every item?

```
<h2 class="title">{{title}} <i class="em em-shopping_bags"></i></h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-2 col-sm-6">

    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" ng-repeat='item in itemsArray'>
      <img class="card-img-top" ng-src={{item.img}} alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.name}}</p>
        <p class="price">{{ item.price | currency }}</p>
        <a href="#"  class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="addTo(item)"><i class="em em-shopping_trolley"></i>  Add to cart <span class="number">{{ item.quantity }}</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is you want to repeat the parent of the card, not cards within it

Comment: @charlietfl yes

Comment: That's as simple as moving the `ng-repeat` up to that parent

Comment: @charlietfl i want to build each item in a row and make it adaptive

Comment: Angular and AngularJS are not the same thing. Also, are you sure entire BS is not working or simply your result is not what you suspected, those are two different things..

Comment: @charlietfl you mean attach ng-repeat to  row or container?

Comment: To the `<div class="col-lg-4..." ng-repeat="...`